# how to stop a package message when we load it?

Tags: r, function, package

How can I prevent the `--- biotools version 4.0` message produced at the start of each new `library(biotools)` call?

I have tried the following without success:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(biotools))
detach(package:biotools)
suppressStartupMessages(library(biotools))
detach(package:biotools)
suppressMessages(library(biotools))
detach(package:biotools)
suppressWarnings(library(biotools))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to capture the printed version as a string with `capture.output` and then wrap with `invisible`.  The `suppressPackageStartupMessages` will prevent the printing of usual messages of attaching other packages/masking of functions (if any) and whatever left over was printed gets captured and removed with `invisible`

```
invisible(capture.output(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(biotools))))
```

Comment: Just in case interested, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66759125/8840683) is an interesting question.

Comment: Oops, I mean to say [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66767139/7223434).

Comment: @rnorouzian The input example is giving me errors. can you check

Comment: @rnorouzian I am guessing the issue is becaues of `T`, `F`  may be I have some object names in that.  It is better to specify `TRUE/FALSE`

Comment: Good point! Let's change them to TRUE and FALSE and see what happens.

Comment: @rnorouzian thank you.  I am checking your functions.  It seems that you are doing a simple mistake by `mm$control` after creating a vector `mm <- mm[[1]]`

Comment: @akrun, you mean I remove `mm <- mm[[1]]`? I did that but the same problem still persists.

Comment: @rnorouzian in your function, `dinter` the output is a matrix, what is `clist` and `tlist` doing in the output

Comment: @akrun, it is for simplicity in this toy example. In my actual example `clist` and `tlist` are further processed. But for now the problem is `ctlist` is not recognized, so let's focus o that.

Comment: @rnorouzian Can you check the solution I posted.  The issue in your code is also the way in which those functions are defined and getting used in `mapply/map`