# Appropriate use of `mapply()` to obtain matrix output

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops, mapply

I was wondering how to modify my `mapply` call to avoid getting: `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` after my last line of code?

Note: the use of `matrix(c(1, .1, 2, .2), nrow = 2)` is just for simplicity.

**My expected output is:**

```
$Trus 
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.0  2.0
[2,]  0.1  0.2

$Yu_Chen
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.0  2.0
[2,]  0.1  0.2
```

**My reproducible code is:**

```
ctlist <- function(mm, cont=FALSE, pos=1, outcom=1){
  
  mm <- mm[[1]]
  mm[mm$control==cont & mm$post == pos & mm$outcome == outcom, , drop = FALSE]
}

#=========
dinter <- function(m, pos, outcom){
  
  clist <- ctlist(mm=m, cont=TRUE, pos = pos, outcom = outcom)
  tlist <- ctlist(mm=m, cont=FALSE, pos = pos, outcom = outcom)
  
  matrix(c(1, .1, 2, .2), nrow = 2) # For simplicity
}
#=========
L1 = list(Trus = data.frame(control=c(T,F), post=c(1,1), outcome=c(1,1), time=c(2,2)),
          Yu_Chen = data.frame(control=c(F,F,T,T), post=c(1,2,1,2), outcome=c(1,1,1,1), time=c(1,2,1,2)) )

#=========

G <- function(m){
  
input <- rev(expand.grid(outcom = seq_len(max(m$outcom, na.rm = TRUE)), pos = seq_len(max(m$post, na.rm = TRUE))))
 
mapply(dinter, m=m, input$pos, input$outcom)
  
}
#=========

setNames(lapply(L1, G), names(L1))

#Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
#Called from: ctlist(mm = m, cont = TRUE, pos = pos, outcom = outcom)
```

Comment: The issue will be at `mm$control` after you create `mm <- mm[[1]]`

Comment: Based on how you defined the function i.e. 'dinter', I am not sure why `mapply/Map` is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the function `ctlist`

```
mm <- mm[[1]]
```

updates the 'mm' to a `vector` by extracting the first column.  Now, it doesn't have any dim attributes.  So, if we do the next line, it won't work because those columns are not present as it is a `vector`

```
mm[mm$control==cont & mm$post == pos & mm$outcome == outcom, , drop = FALSE]
```

Now, checking the `dinter`, it is unclear, why the OP created the `clist` and `tlist` and then a `matrix` out of the blue as expected.  It can be simplified with

```
ctlist <- function(mm, cont=FALSE, pos=1, outcom=1){ 
  mm[mm$control==cont & mm$post == pos & mm$outcome == outcom, , drop = FALSE]
 }


lapply(L1, function(m) {

 input <- rev(expand.grid(outcom = seq_len(max(m$outcom,
      na.rm = TRUE)), pos = seq_len(max(m$post, na.rm = TRUE))))     
      dinter(m, pos = 1, outcom = 1)

 })
#$Trus
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.0  2.0
#[2,]  0.1  0.2

#$Yu_Chen
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.0  2.0
#[2,]  0.1  0.2
```

---

If we are applying the `dinter` on each element of 'input$pos', 'input$outcom', then the `m` should be the same.  In the OP's code, 'm' is also an input to `mapply/Map`.  As 'm' is a data.frame, the unit is a column.  So, it loops over the columns, while the loop for input$pos and input$outcom is a single element (creating an issue in the 'ctlist' function which expects 'mm' as a data.frame along with the fact that length of input$pos and the number of columns of 'mm' differ)

```
lapply(L1, function(m) {

     input <- rev(expand.grid(outcom = seq_len(max(m$outcom, na.rm = TRUE)), pos = seq_len(max(m$post, na.rm = TRUE))))
     
     Map(dinter, MoreArgs = list(m = m), pos = input$pos, outcom = input$outcom)
    

})
#$Trus
#$Trus[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.0  2.0
#[2,]  0.1  0.2


#$Yu_Chen
#$Yu_Chen[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.0  2.0
#[2,]  0.1  0.2

#$Yu_Chen[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.0  2.0
#[2,]  0.1  0.2
```

If we want to flatten the list, use `c` with `do.call`

```
do.call(c, lapply(L1, function(m) {

 input <- rev(expand.grid(outcom = seq_len(max(m$outcom, 
     na.rm = TRUE)), pos = seq_len(max(m$post, na.rm = TRUE))))
 Map(dinter, MoreArgs = list(m = m), pos = input$pos, 
         outcom = input$outcom)
   }))
```

Comment: @rnorouzian As I mentioned earlier, your `dinter` is returning a matrix as output.  So, if you are looping over each value of columns of 'input', I am not sure I understand  the logic correctly.

Comment: @rnorouzian There are some doubts.  Are you using `m` the same for each value of input$pos and input$outcom.  Because of your simplified expected output, it is so difficult to know your exact expectations

Comment: @rnorouzian When we don't worry about  the output, it results in error because `Map` or `mapply` loops over each corresponding element of the inputs.  So, `mapply(dinter, m=m, input$pos, input$outcom)` implies that it loops over each column of 'm', each element of 'pos' and each element of 'outcom'

Comment: @rnorouzian Ok, and what would be the `m` in each loop?  Would it remain the same?

Comment: @rnorouzian For the 'Yu_chen', you get two matrices because there are two rows of 'input'

Comment: @rnorouzian your function returns a `matrix`.  Not clear.  Do you want to flatten the list so that it will be a list of 3 elements instead of nested list?

Comment: @rnorouzian i posted a solution there